# Request failed with status code InternalServerError

Tags: c#

Tengo este método que invoca una API cuando lo ejecuta el Postman, se ejecuta correctamente, pero al hacerlo desde C# con RestClient obtengo lo siguiente

ErrorException = {"Solicitud fallida con código de estado InternalServerError"}

¿Qué me estoy perdiendo?

```
public async Task IndexAsync()
            {
            try
                {
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate
                    {
                        return true;
                        };
                var url = "https://127.0.0.1:50000/b1s/v1/Login";
                var client = new RestClient(url);
                var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.Post);
                request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                var body = new
                    {
                    CompanyDB = "NATAL",
                    Password = "3485*",
                    UserName = "nager"
                    };
                var bodyy = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);
                request.AddParameter("application/json", bodyy, ParameterType.RequestBody);
                RestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
                var output = response.Content;
                MessageBox.Show(output + response.ErrorException.Message + response.ErrorMessage);
                }
            catch (Exception ex)
                {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Cuando hiciste debugging, en cuál línea generó la excepción?

Comment: Como tal no salta  una excepción solo saca el mensaje en esta linea  ->    RestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);